# Magento2 - Attribute taking 0 as default value

Tags: magento2.3, product-attribute, custom-attributes

I have a strange issue and not sure what is wrong, I have identical attributes (see image below), but the strange part is when I keep **Metal 02 Weight** blank and save the product its taking 0 value automatically, while this is not happening with Metal 01 Weight, can anyone help me how to find out the reason.

I have `cleared / flushed all caches`, all `indexes are reindexed`, completely removed `generated` , `static folders` and recompiled everything, still no effect.

[image: Database Screenshot of both attributes]

Comment: can you please share the code/script on how did you created those attributes?

Comment: those were manually created attributes from admin area, shared the database screenshot to show that both attributes are identical in terms of configuration but second one is behaving wrong

Comment: Did you solve this in the end? I have the same issue, it seems to happen once an attribute has been saved with 0 one time, that then becomes the default. (I know this should be a comment but it won't let me add a comment)

Comment: @sevenstar No I couldn't, finally I deleted and recreated attribute and uploaded products data again. :(